# I hate to see you hurting

Tags: transitivity, middle-voice

Someone is hurt by a betrayal.

> 1. I hate to see you hurting.
> 2. I hate to see you being hurt.

Is #2 correct and equally used?
I don't see the logic of #1. It sounds like the person is hurting (himself).

Comment: What is a "betrail"?

Comment: @user3169 I'm pretty sure that should be "betrayal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "hurt" has slightly different meanings when used transitively or intransitively. Transitively, it means to *cause* harm or pain:

> Jasper’s unkind remarks **hurt** my feelings.
>
> When we were wrestling, Jasper **hurt** my arm.

Intransitively, it means to *be in pain*:

> Ever since the wrestling match, my arm has **hurt**.
>
> This spider-bite **hurts**!

So, "I hate to see you hurting" (intransitive) means the same as "I hate to see you in pain."

"I hate to see you being hurt" (transitive, passive) means "I hate to see someone else causing you pain."

---

By the way, "hurt" is also an irregular verb: its past tense and past participle are both "hurt", as illustrated by the examples above.

Comment: Thank you, Ben and Chris. I got the concept of transitive and intransitive. But then, If "being hurt"(passive) is akward, than I guess " are you hurt" also isn't quite correct way to say ? How about following sentences: 1. Have you hurt?(you fell on the ground)  2. Have you hurt your knee?  3. Did you hurt your knee (instead of did you get hurt on your knee, or have you got hurt on your knee).

Comment: Actually, "being hurt" is not awkward at all. That's how you express "A hurt B" passively: "B was hurt by A". If you omit the agent, it still works like an ordinary passive verb: "B was hurt." So, these are all good and quite ordinary: 1. "Have you been hurt?" 2. "Have you hurt your knee?" 3. "Did you hurt your knee?" Here's a sentence that's so common, it's worth memorizing: "Does it hurt?" (referring to a wound or a place on the body). This one uses the intransitive form, since it's just asking if the person feels pain at the wound.

Comment: BTW, from my AmE perspective, "I hate to see you being hurt" is fine. It just emphasizes the role of the betrayer and implies that the betrayal is in the present. "I hate to see you hurting" emphasize the pain by omitting any suggestion of the betrayer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think #1 sounds like the person is inflicting the hurt upon themselves — quite the opposite — "hurting" very strongly sounds like something which is happening against the will of the person being affected.

The latter, "I hate to see you being hurt", sounds far less idiomatic to me as a BrE speaker. It's too long and roundabout. You could, perhaps, use "I hate to see you hurt like this", but I think "being" is too strong here (it almost sounds like physical hurt is happening right at the moment of conversation).

Use the former if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting technical, I'd say you can use both because it's more of a prose style choice. You can also go with "I hate seeing you (to see you) getting/being hurt." Or "I hate that you're hurting."

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I hate to see you hurting.

In this situation, the person was betrayed and now is continuously suffering. Here *hurting* indicates a continuing condition.

> 2) I hate to see you being hurt.

In this situation, the person was betrayed, but maybe this was not the first time. In that case, the person would be repeatedly hurt. You would hate to see that happen, of course.